# Are questions about robot vacuums on-topic?

Tags: discussion

We have an interesting question about a Xiaomi robot vacuum over on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/1367083/rogue-start-up-of-robot-sweeper

Unfortunately it is off-topic there as it is not considered a computer or personal computing device.

As it is a question about a smart home device, and, more importantly, about the remote control/startup of the device (rather than, say, the vacuum motor) I am curious if it is on-topic here?

Answer (score 7):

In this example, the question asked is just a 'generic routing table' issue, and not specific to home automation or internet connected devices (the asker seems to think they have identified the cause of the problem).

Judging from one of the answers, the problem was actually firmware/operation of the device *in it's IoT mode* so the most useful answer relates to the actual device. It seems that the answer is on-topic here since it relates to IoT systems testing and reliability (a big issue with OTA firmware).

Working out up front if these 'generic' seeming questions have any device specific aspects is hard, this surely isn't the best place to be asking about iptables.

Answer (score 6):

As is always the case with this sort of question, it would depend on what is being asked.

I see no problem at all with questions asking how to integrate these devices into, and control them from, an IoT network.  That is surely the purpose of this site.

If you ask how to repair a motor or change a warning light, the matter is debatable.  That isn't directly related to the Internet of Things.